# mysql how to get the last inserted row values in a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am writing a trigger after insert event on a table. This is the table

```
    CREATE TABLE `orderitem` (
       `orderItemId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `orderItemQuantity` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
       `stockId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
       `rate` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
       `orderId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`orderItemId`)
    )
```

Inside the trigger I need the values inserted for the current row(not only the id) inside the trigger. In T-SQL we can use the inserted table but in MySQL I could not find anything like that. How can I get those values?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use OLD. or NEW. since this trigger is fired after the insert both values are the same. You can access all properties of the interred row (if it is a row level trigger) by using:

```
NEW.orderItemID
NEW.rate
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you use the keyworkd NEW instead of Inserted.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html